# ASP.NET WebApi Custom Serialization

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have an action method which returns a DataRow object. Unfortunately the webapi serializer doesn't serialize the object properly. Is there any place where I can place a custom serialization code just for this particular type ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll probably want to create a custom MediaTypeFormatter that returns true for DataRow-typed objects in its CanWrite method.

Here's a good starting point for how to write and register your own formatter:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/media-formatters

Comment: Yeah, thats what I was looking for, thaks.